# Does bittorrent need a proxy?

Tags: linux, proxy, bittorrent

I want to use one of my Debian servers for a "torrent" machine.

I have utorrent on my gaming machine which doesn't require a proxy. But it said on a tutorial that you need a proxy with bittorrent.

Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Requiring a proxy doesn't depend on the client software but on your network configuration. If your server is running behind a proxy, you will have to configure that in the torrent client software. If your server is behind NAT or firewall, you don't need to configure a proxy but there is an additional port configuration.